# Setting "USEPMTIMER" with BCDEDIT

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, bcd

What's the correct way to set the "USEPMTIMER" value with BCDEDIT (i.e. for Vista/Windows 7)? There's plenty of information around regarding setting it in boot.ini, but none that details how to set it using BCEDIT.

Answer (score 2):

```
bcdedit /set {default} useplatformclock true
```

Comment: For the above answer and so as not to have to start a new thread, for Windows 7, what is typed in place of {default}?

Comment: {default} *is* what I wanted to type. It is not a placeholder. More here: http://pastebin.com/9evnaAmC